# Solenoid control over PWM

Tags: pwm, solenoid

I've built a PCB using the below circuit.
I'm having some issues when the solenoid is being energized. It seems as if the kickback is getting into the ground plane affecting the PWM signal. Any help/tips on how to clean up this noise will be appreciated.

The solenoid current is about 1.3Amps for first 10ms @ 90% duty cycle then duty cycle drops to 50% for remainder of actuation. Frequency is set at 24Khz.

EDIT 2:
Added a gate resistor (divider R29,R30) at output of U2.
Seems to have reduced the noise issue.

Ch1 on the scope (green) is looking at the voltage across the solenoid connected at J2. Ch2 on the scope (yellow) is looking at the PWM_ON signal coming from the micro at R2. I've added a resistor divider and seems to have helped a little, but still very crappy.

Also maybe Q1 is not fully turning on?

[image: Circuit]

New Waveform with gate resistors.
[image: NewWave]

Old Waveform with no gate resistors.
[image: Waveform]

Yellow is Q2 Gate and Green is voltage across solenoid.
[image: Q2Gate and Solenoid voltage]

Comment: That schematic makes no sense to me..... what do you think it is supposed to do?

Comment: In short...the PWM signal enables gates of Q2 and Q3 thus engaging Q1 completing the circuit with a return path to GND for the solenoid through Q2. Q2 is shown as having the source connected to D4, but it's actually connected to BGND.

Comment: 80% of those components are unnecessary. Getting rid of those would be a good start.

Comment: It's already built, gotta work with this.

Comment: This looks sort of like it was intended to be a simple on-off driver with a current choke to set-back the current after the solenoid engages. But in this layout that will not work. You also have some beefy gate currents going on because you have no gate resistors and not enough bulk capacitance to handle it. C10 is making it worse and D6 defeats D2 and D3...

Comment: Yes I had actually noticed the issue with the missing gate resistor and actually had a 56uF cap on the 24v line when I took those waveforms, along with an additional 1uF cap on D3, but the noise is still there. Maybe I will try adding a gate resistor and see what happens.

Comment: BTW.. those scope traces are meaningless if you don't explain what they are.

Comment: Don't sprinkle information in the comments. Edit the question.

Comment: @j.valerio, please delete the comments that you have moved to the question.

Comment: What is the solenoid current? And am I correct in thinking that you change the PWM duty cycle after 10 msec? What is the PWM frequency? And what, exactly, do you think the presence of Q1 gets you?

Comment: I've noticed that Q1 is rated for 60V and the spike at turn off is very close to this limit, what you guys think? I've taken Q1 out and replaced it with a short and the noise clears up.

Comment: So I ended up changing R16 to 600Ohms and that helped with the 'noise' issue shown when the PWM duty cycle is reduced. I believe the reason is Q1 was not being turned on fully at the lower duty due to a lower base current. Now I can't really use a small resistance there because power will be high, maybe will need a 2W resistor. I think I might just change Q2 to a P-Channel Mosfet.

Answer (score 1):

That is a clever little circuit! Is it for a diesel fuel injector or something like that? 90% duty to get the solenoid to open, 50% to hold it open. All of the components make sense to get a nice current recirculation in PWM mode then allow a 33V clip of the back EMF after switch off for a quick solenoid close. Maybe you could try slowing down the Q2 switching by adding some gate capacitance? Or provide a separate ground path from Q2 back to star ground to stop the ground bounce. I think Q1 is turning on OK because you are getting a clip of the back EMF in PWM mode.

Comment: Yes similar, but it's actually for a valve to spray some chemicals. I tried slowing Q1 by adding a .1uF cap but it didn't have an effect. I get this about 9V undershoot. Will try providing a separate ground and see if that helps. Added a scope capture of the undershoot.